# Translating "timeliness" in the context of software performance

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, software

I'm trying to translate the following definition of software performance:

> Performance is the degree to which a software system or component meets its objectives for timeliness.

I'm having a hard time translating the word timeliness. Translations like *Rechtzeitigkeit*, *Aktualität*, *Pünktlichkeit* do not seem to fit here.

I found the following definition for information timeliness which seems to capture the meaning pretty well.

> Information Timeliness relates to “the availability of the output information at a time suitable for its use”

So how can I translate timeliness in this context?

Comment: The problem is this is a definition of terms. You have to pick the terms used in German literature on the same topic. My best bet is to look it up there.

Comment: Bummer, the only German source I found does not attempt to translate it: https://books.google.de/books?id=0c4WMU_Iz5cC&lpg=PA46&ots=uyEa19zlse&dq=Performance%20is%20the%20degree%20to%20which%20a%20software%20system%20or%20component%20meets%20its%20objectives%20for%20timeliness.&hl=de&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q=Performance%20is%20the%20degree%20to%20which%20a%20software%20system%20or%20component%20meets%20its%20objectives%20for%20timeliness.&f=false

Comment: Already the english definition is odd. Performance is not a degree, but it measures the degree to which ... And even though I come from software engineering, I have never heard the term timeliness before. But see my suggestion below.

Comment: @Janka I've looked into german literature aswell. Balzert offers another definition citing ISO/IEC 9126-1. I would like to present another definition but maybe I'll just stick with Balzert...

Comment: Why do you think "Rechtzeitigkeit" doesn't fit the bill here? It's a common technical term for *timeliness* in real time IT systems design

Comment: @tofro Just my gut feeling. Feel free to post an answer with references, I might be wrong ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Die Performanz gibt an, wie gut ein Softwaresystem oder eine Softwarekomponente die zeitlichen Vorgaben erfüllt.

You may also interpret *timely* as a synonym for *up-to-date*, which translates to *aktuell*. In this case, the following translation is more apt:

> Die Performanz gibt an, wie gut ein Softwaresystem oder eine Softwarekomponente die Aktualitätsvorgaben erfüllt.

Answer (score 4):

The used translation for the Information timeliness (or the timeliness of the information) is ***Aktualität der Information***

A quote from a [respected source](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32004R0028)

> Aktualität der Information erfasst die Zeitspanne zwischen der
>   Verfügbarkeit einer Information und dem Zeitpunkt, den sie beschreibt.

This term is also used for the software systems. Another [citation](https://books.google.de/books?id=LqqQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=%22Aktualit%C3%A4t+der+Information%22+software&source=bl&ots=aSJlpRK61q&sig=8UWo1DZrQTxTDIh1WAorscL_peE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiphva1g8LUAhWDKFAKHajpAuIQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Aktualit%C3%A4t%20der%20Information%22%20software&f=false) from a book;

> Diese Integritätsinformation gibt dann entsprechende Informationen
>   über die Korrektheit und die Aktualität der Information für die
>   Anwendersoftware.

### Edit

After the comments, I need to research more to find an alternative translation for timeliness for this specific context.

In similar context, **zeitgerecht** is also used to mean the word, which OP looks for.

Comment: The original citation is from *Smith and Williams* and specific for software engineering. You cannot use another definition without making things up.

Comment: @Janka The OP did not ask the translation (or the source) of the citation. He asked the correct translation for the term "Information timelessness". Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: The OP asked how to translate timeliness in that specific context. May I cite her: *I'm trying to translate the following definition of software performance:*

Comment: @Janka I editted my answer. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Your edited part does not describe the *Smith and Williams*' software performance term, but something about software updating practices. That
's a *Verschlimmbesserung*.

Comment: @Janka I do not still think that he asks for the translation of the citation of *Smith and Williams*. I answered the question as I understand the question.

Comment: @Janka is right. I'm looking for a translation in the context I described.

Comment: @Phonolog The context you described is "Software Engineering", right? If so, the translation of "timeliness of the information" is "Aktualität der Information". If you are looking exact translation of the citation, which you gave, my answer may not help you further.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Yes the overall context is software engineering. But I'm looking for a translation in the context of the citation I provided.